# Adding PHP to an if else loop

Tags: php, loop

I want to run some PHP to show custom fields in a page;

```
    <?php

$showExcerpt = get_theme_mod( 'auto_excerpt' , '' );

if( is_single() ) {

    the_content();


} else {

    if ( $post->post_excerpt ) {

            the_excerpt();

        ?>
```

I want to add the code after the content if the page is single, otherwise I do not want to show the PHP if it is just showing an excerpt.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific about what your question is? Are you trying to figure out where to put this code? Is this partial code, because you don't actually use `$showExcerpt` anywhere?

Comment: BTW if-else is not a loop - it doesn’t loop through anything...

Comment: This is a PHP question, not a WordPress question.  You might find better answers in a different stack.